# I need to add a power up option where I can determine the value and select which superhero to give the value to

Tags: java

Here is what I have so far so as you can see I made a class for the powerup but I just keep getting stuck over and over again and ended up getting frustrated cause I couldn't figure it out myself.

```
public class Superhero {
    private int heroStr;
    public int powerUp;
    private String name;

    public Superhero(String name, int heroStr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.heroStr = heroStr;
        System.out.println(name + " Strength is " + heroStr);
    }

    public Superhero(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        heroStr = 10;
        System.out.println(name + " Strength is " + heroStr);
    }

    public int getStr() {
        return heroStr;
    }

    public int powerUp(int powerUp) {
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Superhero Gambit = new Superhero("Gambit");
        Superhero Groot = new Superhero("Groot", 79);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
public void powerUp(int powerUp){
   //this.powerUp is the powerUp in your class, the powerUp without "this" is the powerUp given to the method
   this.powerUp+=powerUp;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting that I am missing a return statement } but I don't see anything

Comment: Change the return type to void like I did above :) Sry for that

Comment: This did not work either assigning any of the heroes with a powerUp did nothing just returned the normal values and ignored the powerUp

Comment: Then you didn't call the method on the correct object.

Answer (score 0):

All you need now is to change your `powerUp` method:

```
public void powerUp(int powerUp) {
    this.heroStr += powerUp;
}
```

and since you instantiated the superheroes, all you need is to call their methods, ex:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    SuperHero gambit = new SuperHero("Gambit",10);
    gambit.powerUp(10);
    System.out.println(gambit.getStr()); //should be 20
}
```

Also, as a side note:

the correct naming convention for variable names is:

```
Class object = new Class();
```

Comment: This did not work the gambit.powerUp(100); did nothing the results I get back is Gambit power is 10 and Groot power is 79.

Comment: ok, you used gambit.heroStr, or gambit.powerUp to get the power?

Comment: using both Gambit.heroStr(100) or Gambit.powerUp(100)